# What is the difference between ~たい and ~ことを望む?

Tags: word-choice

I have been trying to translate some English sentences into Japanese. I have been asking people on OKWAVE to translate these sentences. I am happy to say that the results have been mostly satisfactory. But there have been some instances where the answers seem to be translated into English the same way, but it seems dramatically different in Japanese. My question is intended to explore these instances.

Here is an example:

> Foreign workers do not want to work in that kind of environment.
>
> Japanese translation 1: 外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働くことを望みません。
>
> Japanese translation 2: 外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働きたくありません。

Like I said, both Japanese sentences seem to translate to the same thing in English, but they seem dramatically different.

This leads me to my question. What is the difference between ~たい and ~ことを望む?

Answer (score 0):

As jarmanso7 suggested, I shall split my original into what is now four separate answers.

The following is Answer #1:

> 「～たいです」を使うことができるのは、主語が「私」や「私たち」のときのみです。
>
> 例：私はトイレに行きたいです。〇
>
> あなたはトイレに行きたいです。✖
>
> 彼女はトイレに行きたいです。✖
>
> 私たちは野球を観戦したいです。〇
>
> あなた方は野球を観戦したいです。✖
>
> 外国人労働者は野球を観戦したいです。✖
>
> 「～ことを望みます」は、主語が「私」、「彼／彼女」、「私達」、「彼ら／彼女ら」、どれらの場合でも使用可能です。
>
> 例：私はトイレに行くことを望みます。〇
>
> あなたはトイレに行くことを望みます。✖
>
> 彼はトイレに行くことを望みます。〇
>
> 私たちは野球を観戦することを望みます。〇
>
> あなた方は野球を観戦することを望みます。✖
>
> 外国人労働者は野球を観戦することを望みます。〇
>
> 「～ことを望んでいます」であれば、主語が「私」、「あなた」、「彼／彼女」、「私達」、「あなた方」、「彼ら／彼女ら」、どれらの場合でも使用可能です。
>
> 例：私はトイレに行くことを望んでいます。〇
>
> 彼はトイレに行くことを望んでいます。〇
>
> あなたはトイレにいくことを望んでいます。〇
>
> 私たちは野球を観戦することを望んでいます。〇
>
> 外国人労働者は野球を観戦することを望んでいます。〇
>
> あなた方は野球を観戦することを望んでいます。〇

My translation of the above is as follows:

Being able to use “～たいです” is only when the subject is “私” or “私たち”.

Eg. 私はトイレに行きたいです。[Eng. I want to go to the bathroom] ✓

あなたはトイレに行きたいです。[Eng. You want to go to the bathroom] ✗

彼女はトイレに行きたいです。[Eng. She wants to go to the bathroom] ✗

私たちは野球を観戦したいです。[Eng. We want to watch a baseball game] ✓

あなた方は野球を観戦したいです。[Eng. You guys want to watch a baseball game] ✗

外国人労働者は野球を観戦したいです。[Eng. Foreign workers want to watch a baseball game] ✗

“～ことを望みます” can be used in any case where the subject is “私”, “彼／彼女”, “私達”, or “彼ら／彼女ら”.

Eg. 私はトイレに行くことを望みます。[Eng. I want to go to the bathroom] ✓

あなたはトイレに行くことを望みます。[Eng. You want to go to the bathroom] ✗

彼はトイレに行くことを望みます。[Eng. He wants to go to the bathroom] ✓

私たちは野球を観戦することを望みます。[Eng. We want to watch a baseball game] ✓

あなた方は野球を観戦することを望みます。[Eng. You guys want to watch a baseball game] ✗

外国人労働者は野球を観戦することを望みます。[Eng. Foreign workers want to watch a baseball game] ✓

If it is “～ことを望んでいます”, it can be used in any case where the subject is “私”, “あなた”, “彼／彼女”, “私達”, “あなた方” or “彼ら／彼女ら”.

Eg. 私はトイレに行くことを望んでいます。[Eng. I want to go to the bathroom] ✓

彼はトイレに行くことを望んでいます。[Eng. He wants to go to the bathroom] ✓

あなたはトイレにいくことを望んでいます。[Eng. You want to go to the bathroom] ✓

私たちは野球を観戦することを望んでいます。[Eng. We want to watch a baseball game] ✓

外国人労働者は野球を観戦することを望んでいます。[Eng. Foreign workers want to watch a baseball game] ✓

あなた方は野球を観戦することを望んでいます。[Eng. You guys want to watch a baseball game] ✓

I tried to be careful in translating this answer into English, but there is a chance that I have gotten it wrong. If you are bilingual in Japanese and English, please do not hesitate to point out mistakes, so that I may correct them.

Here is the original link: https://okwave.jp/qa/q9579170.html?by=datetime&order=ASC#a_area

Answer (score 0):

The following is Answer #2:

> 英語の文章: Foreign workers want to work in that kind of environment.　を「外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働きたいです」と訳したとする日本文に違和感を覚えます。
>
> 理由は「たい」は誰でもは使えず、「私」のような一人称の場合か、自分で言えない人の代弁者として「この子おしっこしたいんです」という場合だと思います。
>
> 後の場合でも「ん」を入れて、第三者として「外」から見た状況から判断して、「～なの（あるいは「ん」）です」と弁明する場合に使うと思います。
>
> ですから「～はその様な環境下で働きたいです」は話し手が外国人労働者の代弁者である時に限られ、それでも「～働きたいのです」とのを入れる方が自然です。
>
> したがって、自然な訳はただ一つですから「「～たい」と「～ことを望む」の違いは何ですか？」 というご質問は不要になります。

My translation of the above is as follows:

I feel discomfort with the Japanese sentence which I assume you translated the English sentence “Foreign workers want to work in that kind of environment,” into “外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働きたいです”.

I think that the reason is that “たい” cannot be used by everybody, and that it is cases in the first-person such as “私” or cases where you say “この子おしっこしたいんです” [Eng. The reason is this child wants to pee] as a spokesperson for people who cannot speak for themselves.

I think that you insert “ん” even in the latter case, and use it in cases where you judge from a situation that you saw from “the outside” as a third party, and explain it with “～なの(or “ん”)です”.

Therefore, “～はその様な環境下で働きたいです” is restricted to times when the speaker is a spokesperson for foreign workers, and even then, it is more natural to insert “の” into “～働きたいのです”.

Consequently, since there is only one natural translation, your question “What is the difference between ‘～たい’ and ‘～ことを望む’?” becomes unnecessary.

I tried to be careful in translating this answer into English, but there is a chance that I have gotten it wrong. If you are bilingual in Japanese and English, please do not hesitate to point out mistakes, so that I may correct them.

Here is the original link: https://okwave.jp/qa/q9579170.html?by=datetime&order=ASC#a_area

Answer (score 0):

The following is Answer #3:

> 「～たい」は「自分の希望を示す」時に用いる表現です。 他者に用いる時は「他者の状態を言い表す」事なので「～たい」を使う場合は「～たいと思う（≒望む）」となります。
>
> 「want」を直訳すると「希望する」となります。 「希望する」が「望む」という簡単な表現に言い替えらてれます。
>
> 「want」には表現の対象となる人称の使い分けは有りませんが、 「～たい」を用いる場合には他の単語を加えたり微妙な使い分けが生じます。
>
> 「want」は人称を選ばない単語なので、 日本語に直訳する時には、人称で区別しない「望む」のほうが無難な翻訳となります。
>
> …「want」≒「望む」＞「～たい」
>
> 和訳1…当事者の状態を「説明」してると解釈されます。
>
> 和訳2…当事者の望みを「代弁」してると解釈されます。

My translation of the above is as follows:

“～たい” is an expression that you use when “you show your own desires”. When you use it for other people, in the case where you use “～たい” because it is the act of “verbalizing other people's situations”, it will become “～たいと思う(≈望む)”.

If you translate “want” literally, it will become “希望する”. “希望する” is reworded as a simple expression called “望む”.

There is no proper use of the person that is subject to the expression for “want”, but in cases where you use “～たい”, you will add other words and subtle proper uses will result from it.

Because “want” is a word that does not choose the person, when you literally translate it into Japanese, it will result in the more acceptable translation of “望む” which does not distinguish between persons.

...“want” ≈ “望む” > “～たい”

Japanese translation 1...It will be interpreted as “explaining” the situation of the party concerned.

Japanese translation 2...It will be interpreted as “speaking for” the desires of the party concerned.

I tried to be careful in translating this answer into English, but there is a chance that I have gotten it wrong. If you are bilingual in Japanese and English, please do not hesitate to point out mistakes, so that I may correct them.

Here is the original link: https://okwave.jp/qa/q9579170.html?by=datetime&order=ASC#a_area

Answer (score 0):

The following is Answer #4:

> 和訳2:外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働きたいです。
>
> これはやはり日本語としては不自然な表現と言わざるを得ませんが、機械翻訳では仕方がないでしょう。
>
> 英語カテでご説明しましたように、「希望します」は文語的表現、または"formal"な表現であるということになります。これに対して「～たいと思います」や「～たいです」は口語的表現または"informal"な表現ということになります。
>
> 翻訳では必ず「口語訳」か「文語訳」のどちらかを選ぶことになります。両方混ぜてしまうと「使いものにならない訳文」ということになります。

My translation of the above is as follows:

“和訳2:外国人労働者はその様な環境下で働きたいです。”
I cannot help but say that this is also an unnatural expression for Japanese, but there probably is no help for machine translation.

As I explained in the English Language Cat., It follows that “希望します” is a literary expression or “formal” expression. In contrast to this, it follows that “～たいと思います” or “～たいです” are colloquial expressions or “informal” expressions.

For translation, you will inevitably end up choosing either a “colloquial translation” or a “literary translation”. If you happen to mix the two, it follows that they will be “useless translated sentences”.

I tried to be careful in translating this answer into English, but there is a chance that I have gotten it wrong. If you are bilingual in Japanese and English, please do not hesitate to point out mistakes, so that I may correct them.

Here is the original link: https://okwave.jp/qa/q9579170.html?by=datetime&order=ASC#a_area